# KVM/QEMU hot-replace raw disk

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, replace, storage

One of VM disks got damaged and I'm trying to replace it online, without rebooting VM. However when I use:

```
drive_add virtio1 file=/dev/sdb,format=raw,if=virtio,cache=none,aio=native
```

in VM monitor QEMU fails with:

```
Can't hot-add drive to type 7
```

disk is not mounted/used by OS in guest machine.

Comment: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Hotadd_pci_devices